# Mapping incorrect values

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to map multiple observables into one single observable use RXJS `CombineLatest`. This was previously working when I was trying to map 6 observables but when adding an additional 5, the compiler seems to get confused about the mapping. This is the logic in question:

```
interface ReferenceData {
    observableOne: ArrOne[];
    observableTwo: ArrTwo[];
    observableThree: ArrThree[];
    observableFour: ArrFour[];
    observableFive: ArrFive[];
    observableSix: ArrSix[];
    observableSeven: ArrSeven[];
    observableEight: ArrEight[];
    observableNine: ArrNine[];
    observableTen: ArrTen[];
    observableEleven: ArrEleven[];
}

export class ReviewComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

 observableOne$: Observable<ArrOne[]>;
 observableTwo$: Observable<ArrTwo[]>;
 observableThree$: Observable<ArrThree[]>;
 observableFour$: Observable<ArrFour[]>;
 observableFive$: Observable<ArrFive[]>;
 observableSix$: Observable<ArrSix[]>;
 observableSeven$: Observable<ArrSeven[]>;
 observableEight$: Observable<ArrEight[]>;
 observableNine$: Observable<ArrNine[]>;
 observableTen$: Observable<ArrTen[]>;
 observableEleven$: Observable<ArrEleven[]>;

 referenceData$: Observable<ReferenceData>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getReferenceData();
        this.createSingleReferenceDataObservable();
    }

  getReferenceData() {
        this.observableOne$ = this.entityService.get('TestDataOne');
        this.observableTwo$ = this.entityService.get('TestDataTwo');
        this.observableThree$ = this.entityService.get('TestDataThree');
        this.observableFour$ = this.entityService.get('TestDataFour');
        this.observableFive$ = this.entityService.get('TestDataFive');
        this.observableSix$ = this.entityService.get('TestDataSix');
        this.observableSeven$ = this.entityService.get('TestDataSeven');
        this.observableEight$ = this.entityService.get('TestDataEight');
        this.observableNine$ = this.entityService.get('TestDataNine');
        this.observableTen$ = this.entityService.get('TestDataTen');
        this.observableEleven$ = this.entityService.get('TestDataEleven');
   }

    createSingleReferenceDataObservable() {
            this.referenceData$ = combineLatest([
                this.observableOne$, 
                this.observableTwo$, 
                this.observableThree$, 
                this.observableFour$, 
                this.observableFive$, 
                this.observableSix$, 
                this.observableSeven$, 
                this.observableEight$, 
                this.observableNine$, 
                this.observableTen$, 
                this.observableEleven$
            ])
            .pipe(
                map(([
                    ArrOne, 
                    ArrTwo, 
                    ArrThree, 
                    ArrFour, 
                    ArrFive, 
                    ArrSix, 
                    ArrSeven, 
                    ArrEight, 
                    ArrNine, 
                    ArrTen, 
                    ArrEleven
                ]) => {
                    return {
                        ArrOne, 
                        ArrTwo, 
                        ArrThree, 
                        ArrFour, 
                        ArrFive, 
                        ArrSix, 
                        ArrSeven, 
                        ArrEight, 
                        ArrNine, 
                        ArrTen, 
                        ArrEleven
                    }
                })
            );
        }
    
    }
```

The compiler is giving the following error:

> Type 'Observable<{ ArrOne: ArrOne[]; ArrTwo: ArrOne[]; ArrThree:
> ArrOne[]; ArrFour: ArrOne[]; ArrFive: ArrOne[]; ArrSix: ArrOne[];
> ArrSeven: ArrOne[]; ArrEight: ArrOne[]; ArrNine: ArrOne[]; ArrTen:
> ArrOne[]; ArrEleven: ArrOne[]; }>' is not assignable to type
> 'Observable'.   Type '{ ArrOne: ArrOne[]; ArrTwo:
> ArrOne[]; ArrThree: ArrOne[]; ArrFour: ArrOne[]; ArrFive: ArrOne[];
> ArrSix: ArrOne[]; ArrSeven: ArrOne[]; ArrEight: ArrOne[]; ArrNine:
> ArrOne[]; ArrTen: ArrOne[]; ArrEleven: ArrOne[]; }' is missing the
> following properties from type 'ReferenceData': observableOne,
> observableTwo, observableThree, observableFour, and 7 more.

It's strange because if I reduce the number of observables to six and delete the corresponding values from the `ReferenceData` interface, the compiler doesn't throw this error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RxJS combineLatest also has another overload where you can pass in an object, which would let you skip the `map` too:

```
        this.referenceData$ = combineLatest({
            ArrOne: this.observableOne$, 
            ArrTwo: this.observableTwo$, 
            ArrThree: this.observableThree$, 
            ArrFour: this.observableFour$, 
            ArrFive: this.observableFive$, 
            ArrSix: this.observableSix$, 
            ArrSeven: this.observableSeven$, 
            ArrEight: this.observableEight$, 
            ArrNine: this.observableNine$, 
            ArrTen: this.observableTen$, 
            ArrEleven: this.observableEleven$
        });
```

Maybe this one works better. It could be the array one doesn't work because TS might have a limit on how many values it can infer from a tuple.

Comment: I think that has overload has been deprecated:

"@deprecated — resultSelector no longer supported, pipe to map instead"

Comment: @BailP I think you might be using an old version of rxjs? The last few versions that overload is definetly not deprecated. What version do you have? I'm using 7.3 and that's fine there, and the official docs also have an example with the Dictionary overload https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest

Comment: Apologies, yes you are right. I've upgraded to 7.5 and it's no longer deprecated. I (arguably logically) assumed if it was deprecated in an older version, then all newer versions would also be deprecated. Upgrading the version also resolved the original issue I was having so thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
[
                    ArrOne, 
                    ArrTwo, 
                    ArrThree, 
                    ArrFour, 
                    ArrFive, 
                    ArrSix, 
                    ArrSeven, 
                    ArrEight, 
                    ArrNine, 
                    ArrTen, 
                    ArrEleven
                ]
```

```
this is an array of type `ArrOne[] | ArrTwo[] | ArrThree[] | ArrFour[] | ArrFive[] | ArrSix[] | ArrSeven[] | ArrEight[] | ArrNine[]` and you cannot just say that `Apple | Pear` is `Apple` only the other way round.

So you need to:
```

```
    return {
                        ArrOne as ArrOne[], 
                        ArrTwo as ArrTwo[],  
                        ...
                    }
```

Comment: Hi Vulwsztyn, thanks for your response. Unfortunately you can't use type casting within that scope. Just receive the compile error:

"No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'as'. Either declare one or provide an initializer"

Comment: Also, it doesn't explain why it works without type casting but with fewer observables?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution an the end of the error msg

> is missing the following properties from type 'ReferenceData': observableOne, observableTwo, observableThree, observableFour, and 7 more.

The problem is that in `ReferenceData` you have defined the properies names as `observableOne, observableTwo,...`

```
interface ReferenceData {
    observableOne: ArrOne[];
    observableTwo: ArrTwo[];
    ...
}
```

But in the map you are returning an object with properties named as `ArrOne, ArrTwo,...`

So you either change the mapping function so the returned properties names match the interface.

```
.pipe( 
  map(([observableOne, observableTwo,...]) => 
    ({observableOne, observableTwo,...})
  )
)
```

Or you use directly the object parameter signature of `combineLatest`

```
this.referenceData$ = combineLatest({
  observableOne: this.observableOne$, 
  observableTwo: this.observableTwo$,
  ...
});
```

Cheers